Convert Date Format %Y%m%d%H%M%S to unix epoch format
I am trying all the methods but I get this error:
I want to convert this format to epoch -->
date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"

example --> 20240913235959
I also tried other formats such as:
date "+%Y%m%d %H%M%S"
date "+%Y-%m%-d% H:%M:%S"

but every time I pass time to this command it throws an error.
what I want is to  convert Date & Time to epoch, the thing is no other format like 2022-11-09T14:41:15.555641007Z can be used?

none of the date commands you've provided actually generate an epoch value; please update the question to show your coding attempts at every time I pass time to this command

where is the datetime strimg coming from? are you generating it and if so, why not generate the epoch directly (eg, date '+%s')

also update the question with the complete error(s)

Which date implementations are available to you? Some of them (e.g. busybox date) support a strptime-like format specifier for the input as well as the output

"every time I pass time to this command it throws an error" - what exactly are you doing and what is the resulting error message?

"I am trying all the methods" - really?  I suspect there's at least one method you haven't tried, else it would be working now.  You should show us what you tried, and how the results are different to what you want.

There is a standard strptime() UNIX function¹ to parse a timestamp based on a format specification such as %Y%m%d%H%M%S and the standard mktime() POSIX function to convert the result into epoch time and most programming languages and date utility implementations (with the notable exception of GNU date) and some shells have an interface to that or similar.
Now a timestamp such as 20231029012345 doesn't carry any information about the time zone. So to convert it from that, which is clock time relative to a time zone, to epoch time, which is a representation of an exact moment in time independent of any time zone, you need to specify the time zone.
As it happens, in many of the time zones of Western Europe there were two instants in time when the clock said 20231029012345. For instance, in Scotland where I write this, that was both at Unix epoch 1698539025 (before the switch to winter time) and 1698542625 (after the switch):
$ export TZ=Europe/London
$ for t (1698539025 1698542625) strftime '%Y%m%d%H%M%S can be %s (actually %FT%T.%N%z)' $t
20231029012345 can be 1698539025 (actually 2023-10-29T01:23:45.000000000+0100)
20231029012345 can be 1698542625 (actually 2023-10-29T01:23:45.000000000+0000)

So if 20231029012345 is meant to be a representation of the local time, it is not possible to convert that to epoch seconds reliably. Implementations will have to pick one for those timestamps that occur twice.
Generic programming languages will give you some control over whether you want to interpret the timestamp as UTC time or in the local timezone or any other timezone, the rest will generally interpret it in local time (with the caveat mentioned above), but you can set the $TZ environment variable to UTC0 for that local time to become UTC.
Examples below are with $TZ globally set as export TZ=Pacific/Auckland as it's nicely far away from UTC.
Besides GNU awk already mentioned by @EdMorton, there's
date utilities

FreeBSD date (with -f added in 1997), OpenBSD date (since 2019), NetBSD date (since 2022):
$ date -jf %Y%m%d%H%M%S 20240913235959 +%s
1726228799
$ date -ujf %Y%m%d%H%M%S  20240913235959 +%s
1726271999
$ TZ=UTC0 date -jf %Y%m%d%H%M%S 20240913235959 +%s
1726271999


ast-open date (or the date builtin of ksh93 if included; rarely these days) where the -p/--parse option was added in or before 2004:
$ date -p %Y%m%d%H%M%S -d 20240913235959 +%s
1726228799
$ date -up %Y%m%d%H%M%S -d 20240913235959 +%s
1726271999
$ TZ=UTC0 date -p %Y%m%d%H%M%S -d 20240913235959 +%s
1726271999


busybox and toybox date with -D added respectively in 2006 and 2015.
$ date -D %Y%m%d%H%M%S -d 20240913235959 +%s
1726228799
$ date -uD %Y%m%d%H%M%S -d 20240913235959 +%s
1726271999
$ TZ=UTC0 date -uD %Y%m%d%H%M%S -d 20240913235959 +%s
1726271999

(beware timezone support may be disabled at build time)


GNU date supports parsing times (provided either via -d <timespec> or -f <file-containing-timespecs>, or -f - for those <timespec>s to be read from stdin, unrelated to the -f <input-format> option of BSD date) but in current versions only in a fixed set of input formats. So you need to convert that 20240913235959 to one of them such as the 2024-09-13T23:59:59  standard ISO-8601 format:
$ echo 20240913235959 | sed -E 's/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)/\1-\2-\3T\4:\5:/' | date -f- +%s
1726228799
$ echo 20240913235959 | sed -E 's/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)/\1-\2-\3T\4:\5:/' | date -uf- +%s
1726271999
$ echo 20240913235959 | sed -E 's/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)/\1-\2-\3T\4:\5:/' | TZ=UTC0 date -f- +%s
1726271999

Shells

zsh with -r added to its strftime builtin in 2006:
$ zmodload zsh/datetime
$ strftime -r %Y%m%d%H%M%S 20240913235959
1726228799
$ TZ=UTC0 strftime -r %Y%m%d%H%M%S 20240913235959
1726271999

See also the -s var option to return the result into $var rather than printing it.

ksh93 (with %T added to its printf builtin in 1999). It's a bit awkward there as the list of formats to recognise on input are to be stored in a file referenced by the $DATEMSK variable.
$ echo %Y%m%d%H%M%S > ~/.datemsk
$ export DATEMSK=~/.datemsk
$ printf '%(%s)T\n' 20240913235959
1726228799
$ TZ=UTC0 printf '%(%s)T\n' 20240913235959
1726271999



Programming languages
(to name only a few)

TCL (-format option of clock scan added in 2004)
$ tclsh
% clock scan 20240913235959 -format %Y%m%d%H%M%S
1726228799
% clock scan 20240913235959 -format %Y%m%d%H%M%S -gmt true
1726271999


perl (strptime() added to Time::Piece in 2001)
$ perl -MTime::Piece -le 'print localtime->strptime($_, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")->epoch for @ARGV' 20240913235959
1726228799
$ perl -MTime::Piece -le 'print Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")->epoch for @ARGV' 20240913235959
1726271999
$ TZ=UTC0 perl -MTime::Piece -le 'print localtime->strptime($_, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")->epoch for @ARGV' 20240913235959
1726271999


ruby (since 2005):
$ ruby -e 'require "time"; ARGV.each {|t| puts Time.strptime(t, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S").to_i}' 20240913235959
1726228799
$ TZ=UTC0 ruby -e 'require "time"; ARGV.each {|t| puts Time.strptime(t, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S").to_i}' 20240913235959
1726271999


python3 (time.strptime added to python in 1998):
$ python3 -c 'import time, sys
for arg in sys.argv[1::]:
  print(int(time.mktime(time.strptime(arg, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))))' 20240913235959
1726228799
$ TZ=UTC0 python3 -c 'import time, sys
for arg in sys.argv[1::]:
  print(int(time.mktime(time.strptime(arg, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))))' 20240913235959
1726271999




¹ possibly originating in SunOS 4.1 in 1989.

Using GNU awk for its time library:
$ echo '20240913235959' |
    awk -l time '{print strptime($0,"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}'
1726289999

or, if the gawk time library isn't available on your system and you can't install it, then also GNU awk for the built in mktime():
$ echo '20240913235959' |
    awk '{gsub(/../,"& "); print mktime($1$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7)}'
1726289999

You may want to be something different from echo-ing the input to awk though; the right thing to do in that regard depends on how your input is stored.

With GNU date, bash and its Parameter Expansion:
t="20240913235959"
date -d "${t:0:4}/${t:4:2}/${t:6:2} ${t:8:2}:${t:10:2}:${t:12:2}" +%s

Output:

1726264799


Note that it assumes there's no POSIXLY_CORRECT variable in the environment. Generally, you want to have options (such as -d timespec) before non-option arguments (such as +format)

@StéphaneChazelas: thank you. I moved +%s to last position.

We can cheat and use sed to convert the input into something date likes.
eg
% date -d "$(echo 20240913235959 | sed 's!\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)!\1/\2/\3 \4:\5:\6!')"
Fri Sep 13 23:59:59 EDT 2024

We can then use the +%s to convert to epoch seconds
% date -d "$(echo 20240913235959 | sed 's!\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)!\1/\2/\3 \4:\5:\6!')" +%s
1726286399


You may want to clarify that this is specific to the GNU implementation of date. Many other date implementations don't need that reformatting as you can specify the input format with an additional option (-f, -p, -D depending on implementation, see my answer for details).

Alternatively, with GNU sed, we can get it to execute date for us: echo 20240913235959 | sed -E 's/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)/date -d "\1-\2-\3T\4:\5:\6" +%s/e'.  That's useful if we have a stream of these to convert.

@TobySpeight, GNU sed's e flag runs a shell to interpret the substituted pattern space. That would run a shell for every line. I would personally not touch that e with a barge pole, as it's so easy to cause ACE vulnerabilities with it. Here, if you're going to use GNUisms, it would be much more efficient to use GNU date's -f option as I show in my answer.

Good point @Stéphane.

If you don't trust the libraries, you can perform the conversion yourself; this is Bash, but the same calculation could be done in any language:

D=20240921141157    # example input
tz=$(( 10*3600 ))   # your local timezone incl DST; I'm in Brisbane (UTC+10)

# First, pull it apart. (This will look quite different in other languages.)
# If you already have separate components then you can skip this step
(( y  = 10#${D:0:4},
   mo = 10#${D:4:2},
   d  = 10#${D:6:2},
   h  = 10#${D:8:2},
   mi = 10#${D:10:2},
   s  = 10#${D:12:2} ))

# Pretend that January and February are months 13 and 14 of the previous year (so that leap days are at the end of the "year")
(( mo < 3 && (y--, mo += 12) ))

# Count months and days starting from 0
(( d--, mo -= 3 ))

# Count days since (most recent) 1-March
(( d += mo / 5 * 153, mo %= 5,
   d += mo / 2 * 61, mo %= 2,
   d += mo * 31 ))

# Count days since 1-January-1970
(( d += y / 400 * 146097, y %= 400,
   d += y / 100 * 36524, y %= 100,
   d += y / 4 * 1461, y %= 4,
   d += y * 365,
   d -= 719468 ))

# Convert days, minutes, hours to seconds
(( h  += d * 24,
   mi += h * 60,
   s  += mi * 60 ))

# adjust for your local timezone and DST
(( s -= tz ))

# Check the result. I'm in Brisbane (UTC+10)
echo "Epoch Seconds = $s"

TZ=Australia/Brisbane \
date -d @$s

